# Address Sanitizer exit status

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

Address sanitizer always sets exit status ($?) 1 if it detects any memory leak, even if the test case passed successfully. I am using "$?" in my script to detect test case pass/fail status and need to ignore this mem error. Is there any option to disable this ? For ref we can use below example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *s = malloc(100);
    strcpy(s, "Hello world!");
    printf("string is: %s\n", s);
    //free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc ca.c -o leak -fsanitize=address -static-libasan

```
./leak
string is: Hello world!

=================================================================
==25465==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 100 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x48c1ff in __interceptor_malloc ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x4cb1cd in main (/home/nipandey/junk1/leak+0x4cb1cd)
    #2 0x7f61f8886554 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x22554)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 100 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

echo $?
1

Tries few options but no luck

Comment: so, you want to detect memory leaks, but ignore them?

Comment: I am fine to dump it on a asan.log file that I'll process later to get required data but exit status should not changed due to memory leaks.

Comment: Not sure if I can play with this option to achieve this .

symbolize=1:detect_leaks=1:log_path=asan.log:abort_on_error=0

Comment: then don't use asan for unit tests, you can recompile and rerun them as separate step in pipeline which will ignore exit code

Comment: Yes that is an option but just want to know if there is any such option

Comment: According to [the docu](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags), the option is `exitcode=0`.